# Multiple Models Binding Falied (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i'm trying to get data to my view from multiple models but every time I got an error, I tried a lot to fix this but I was failed...plz help me with this..i am posting my code..n I have created view-models for this

this is a index view

```
@model Stubify.Models.ViewModels.TimeLine

   <div class="media social-box social-composer ">
                <a class="pull-left social-users-avatars" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" width="55" height="55" src="../Content/assets/img/avatar-55.png" alt="Julio Marquez">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body social-body">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.User.Take(1))
                    {
                        <textarea id="new_message" name="new_message" class="textarea span12" placeholder="What's happening, @item.FullName?" cols="10"></textarea>
                    }

                    <div class="social-footer">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn" data-original-title=""><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></a>
                            <a class="btn" data-original-title=""><i class="icon-camera"></i></a>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button">Post</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="NewsFeeds">
                @Html.Partial("_NewsFeeds", Model)
            </div>
            <div id="loading"></div>
```

this is a view model

```
public class TimeLine
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<Users> User { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<UsersPosts> UsersPost { get; set; }
}
```

this is a partial view

```
  @model Stubify.Models.ViewModels.TimeLine
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<div class="social-share-image">
            <img src="../Content/assets/img/gallery/sunset.jpg" alt="Sun Set">
            <div class="social-share-image-text">
                <h4>@item.UserId</h4>
                <p><strong>@item.PostContent!</strong><small> @item.Date <i class="icon-globe"></i></small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

this is a controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null, int? id = 0)
    {
        var viewModel = new TimeLine();

        var page = id ?? 0;

        viewModel.User = db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id)
            .Where(u => searchTerm == null || u.FullName.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)).Take(records);
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_NewsFeeds", GetPaginatedProducts(page));
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

please help me plzzz

Comment: What errors/symptoms do you get? Just stating _"but I was failed"_ does not make this a good question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to get data from two models to a single view..the error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at loop in partial view, if I remove partial view, the code runs correctly but not rendering partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvious problem is that while you fill `viewModel.User = ...` in the Controller, there is no code filling `viewModel.UsersPost = ...` so that one will be `null`.

And I noticed this section that can never work:

```
@model Stubify.Models.ViewModels.TimeLine
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   ...
}
```

`TimeLine` is not a collection (although it contains 2 collections).

This is what you probably meant:

```
@model IEnumerable<Stubify.Models.Models.User>  // my best guess
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Henk is correct.  The model you are passing to the View is a single object, not a collection.  You might consider changing this to (var item in Model.Users).

Comment: @mtm927 I have already passed this but this is not for Users class this is for UsersPosts class and the main one is from User Class..i want to get name from User Class and Post Content from UsersPosts, I think now u guys better understand

Comment: yes, it is not a collection it contains two collections User and UsersPosts

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have read that can u please tell me how I can bind userpost viewmodel in controller?

Comment: Same as you bind the userlist. They are the same in the ViewModel, they need similar treatment.